# PageViewController didFinishAnimating not called all the time

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

PageViewController didFinishAnimating not called when swipe multiple time.

I have a function that recognize that user finish animation swipe and I start to move alone the page every 4 second.

sometimes didFinishAnimating not call in the last swipe.

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {

NSLog(@"\n\n\n didFinishAnimating  \n\n\n");
_isAnimateWorking = NO;

if(completed){
    _currentIndex = _nextIndex;
 }
else
{
    _currentProduct = prev_currentProduct;
   _nextIndex = prev_nextIndex;
}

[self StartMoveAloneTimer];
 }



-(void) StartMoveAloneTimer {
if (_myticker == nil) {
    _myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self selector:@selector(GoToNextPage) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
}
```

Comment: Can you show what's in the StartMoveAloneTimer?

Comment: I edit the question , GoToNextPage move page in page viewcontroler.

Comment: I thought, that you schedule transition from the other thread or something like this. But GoToNextPage will be called on the main thread here, so it's not the problem. I could only recommend add logging to other UIPageViewController delegate methods, replace last controller with other class, log their viewDidAppear, etc. because I didn't have this problem.